# woocommerce custom payment gateway cancel order by customer hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, hook-woocommerce

I try to create my custom payment gateway for woocommerce , but i have small problem in the cancelation process when i call the cancel api for the gateway i use action hook to call my cancelation function

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed','woo_order_status_change_custom' , 10, 3);
   public function woo_order_status_change_custom($order_id, $old_status, $new_status ){

   // custom api code

}
```

and its working fine when i cancel the order from the wp-admin, but when the customer try to cancel his order from his account page the hook not trigger the function .
**Please any one could help with it ??**

Comment: Tell us what you've tried so far and where you're stuck. Your action handler is _empty_.

Comment: all i need is way to trigger the function  when the customer click on the order cancel button in account page but the 'woocommerce_order_status_changed' hook not working with it so i need replacement which works fine with both sides customers and admin side

Comment: By default there is no cancel button for customers in the my account section in WooCommerce. 
It therefore seems that this has been made possible via an extra plugin and you will therefore have to look for the solution in that direction. Without further information it is not immediately possible to answer your question

Comment: i use Twenty Twenty theme and only 2 plugins woocommerce and my custom plugin for the payment gateway , Please check the following link for screenshot from the account page
link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/12ykV2HdDbB3lb6OC3X_pxQ2SYJe6IBfL/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

In that case you need to use the WooCommerce hook named `woocommerce_order_status_cancelled`.

The example are given below

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_cancelled', 'change_the_order_status_to_refund', 10, 1 );

public function change_the_order_status_to_refund( $order_id ){
    //Your code will be here
}
```